# Python Best Syntactic way of Calculating the age based on datetime

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

After searching around the web got the below two ways to get the age of a person.
Just curious to Know if there is better synthetic way of calculating & writing it in 3.x version of python.

First way around ...

```
$ cat birth1.py
#!/grid/common/pkgs/python/v3.6.1/bin/python3
import datetime
year = datetime.datetime.now().year # getting current year from the system
year_of_birth = int(input("Enter Your Birth Year: "))
print("You are  %i Year Old" %  (year - year_of_birth))
```

The Result produced..

```
$ ./birth1.py
Enter Your Birth Year: 1981
You are  37 Year Old
```

Second way around ....

```
$ cat birth2.py
#!/grid/common/pkgs/python/v3.6.1/bin/python3
from datetime import datetime, date

print("Your date of birth (dd/mm/yyyy)")
date_of_birth = datetime.strptime(input("Please Put your age here: "), "%d/%m/%Y")

def calculate_age(born):
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))

age = calculate_age(date_of_birth)
print("You are  %i Year Old." %  (age))
```

The Result produces..

```
$ ./birth2.py
Your date of birth (dd/mm/yyyy)
Please Put your age here: 22/09/2015
You are  2 Year Old.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

```
import datetime as dt


def years_ago(start: str):
    sec_per_year = 365.24 * 24 * 60 * 60
    delta = dt.datetime.now() - dt.datetime.strptime(start, '%d/%m/%Y')
    return delta.total_seconds() / sec_per_year


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(int(years_ago(input('What is your date of birth (dd/mm/yyyy) ? '))))
```

Comment: i'll check it , it sounds great.

Comment: J_H, could you explain the def annotation you have used `(start: str)` , until now as a learner i only know about `(start, str)`.

Comment: I was making it clear that the input `start` is a `str` rather than a `datetime`. Alternatively one could say it in a docstring, but then PyCharm wouldn't know what methods to offer for autocomplete. You can read more about annotations at many places, including: https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2017/10/31/python-3-variable-annotations/